# Insert a new directory path to PATH in .cshrc file fail

Tags: freebsd

I want to add a additional directory to PATH in `.cshrc` in my home directory . 
But after I put the path to it ,It still not working . I don't know what's the problem ...

After I add this directory to `.cshrc` I type the name of program to use it , But it can't find ...

I want to add a directory called .tools in my home directory

The original file

```
set path = (. ~ /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin)
```

After I added

```
set path = (. ~ ~/.tools /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell reads `~/.cshrc` only once, at start-up. Therefore, any changes you make to the file will not be picked up immediately. You can either start a new shell, or type `source ~/.cshrc` to make the current shell reread the file.